# How do i keep a 2 columns and a piechart the same height when changing the size of a window

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

Im working on a project and hit a roadblock where i have two columns, one of them has a pie chart inside and im having issues keeping two columns the same size when adjusting the window size. when i get the 2 columns to stay the same size the pie chart decides to bug out,  how can i keep both columns the same also having the pie chart to adjust correctly without bugging out.

by bugging out i mean the pie chart overlaps off the column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xynx5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91gzO.png)

ive spent hours trying to find a solution, i tried fixing height of both columns (which works until the screen becomes small causing the columns to overlap) and tweaking the size of the pie chart to force the column to match the other one but nothing, im basically stumped.

Heres the html and css of the project:

```
  <div class="container-fluid top-info">
            <div class="row top-info">
                <!--Nutrition value-->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="nutrition">
                        <!--Nutritional value title-->
                        <div class="row nutrition-values">
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <h2>Nutritional Values</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--input box for grams-->
                        <div class="row grams-input">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group grams-row">
                                    <input type="text" name="grams" id="inputg" size="5">
                                    <label for="grams">g</label>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="servingsize">Serving Size per 100/Grams <span class="float-end"></span></li>
                            <li>Carbohydrates: <span class="float-end">5</span></li>
                            <li>Cholesterol: <span class="float-end">56</span></li>
                            <li>Saturated fat: <span class="float-end">5</span></li>
                            <li>Total Fat: <span class="float-end">5</span></li>
                            <li>Fiber Content: <span class="float-end">5</span></li>
                            <li>Potassium <span class="float-end">5</span></li>
                            <li>Protein: <span class="float-end">5</span></li>
                            <li>Sodium:<span class="float-end">5</span></li>
                            <li>Sugar: <span class="float-end">0.6</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Graph-->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="container-fluid graph">
                    <!--calories information heading-->
                        <div class="cal-heading">
                            <h5>100/Grams of Granola Has a total of <span>400 Calories</span></h5>
                        </div>    
                        <!--pie chart graph--> 
                        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
<script>
            new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
              type: 'pie',
              data: {
                labels: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "PHP", "MySql"],
                datasets: [{
                  backgroundColor: ["#e63946", "#254BDD",
                    "#ffbe0b", "#1d3557", "#326998"
                  ],
                  data: [418, 263, 434, 586, 332]
                }]
              },
              options: {
                title: {
                  display: false,
                  text: 'Pie Chart for admin panel'
                },
                responsive: true
              }
            });
          </script>
```

```
.logo{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 35px;
}

#search{
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

.inputstyle {
    padding: 20px !important;
}

#button {
  background-color: #494747;
  color: white;
  width: 8em;
  font-size: 30px !important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-width: 1px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.top-info{
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.nutrition{

    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 23px;

}

.graph{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    }

.nutrition-values{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.grams-input{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h2{
    margin-left: 42px;
}

ul {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
    width: 90%;
}

.servingsize {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#inputg{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 42px;
    height: 40px;
}

label{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.cal-heading{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

span{
    color: #4B8673;
}
```

Comment: You can add the image directly to the question instead of giving the link.